# graphing $f(ax-b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I want to know which of the following methods is right for graphing $f(ax-b)$ from $f(x)$ and why:

Method 1. First Horizontally Translate it ($f(x)$) by $b$, then Horizontally Stretch/Compress it by $a$.

Method 2. First Horizontally Stretch/Compress it by $a$ then Horizontally Translate it by $b/a$.

Method 3. First Horizontally Translate it by $b/a$ then Horizontally Stretch/Compress it by $a$.

Comment: Try it yourself. What happens with $x = 0$ or $x = 1$? Which of the three descriptions give the same answer?

Comment: @Arthur , when i check this solutions, I get that method 1 and 2 is right. but I think method 2 and 3 must be right. I don't know why 3 isn't getting me the right answer.

Comment: Method 3 should also work as long as the stationary point for the stretch is chosen with an x-coordinate of $b/a$. In other words, the stretch should be relative to the line $y=b/a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning $y=f(ax-b)$ inside out by applying the inverse of $f$ (i.e. $f^{-1}$).

$$y=f(ax-b)$$
$$f(ax-b)=y$$
$$f^{-1}(f(ax-b))=f^{-1}(y)$$
$$ax-b=f^{-1}(y)$$
$$ax=f^{-1}(y)+b$$
$$x=\frac{1}{a}(f^{-1}(y)+b)$$
$$x=\frac{1}{a}f^{-1}(y)+\frac{b}{a}$$

It's clear from this approach that we have a compression (with a factor of $a$) "along the x-axis". Notice that I didn't say "along the vertical or horizontal axis". That's because, at this point, I'm looking at the graph with my head tilted to the side (and I'm also looking at it in the mirror, so it gets very confusing). We also have a  positive shift of $\frac{b}{a}$ along the x-axis.

The one problem with this approach is that not all functions are 1-to-1 (and thus invertible). But we can get around this problem just by defining $f$ as a piece-wise function, and performing this process for each of the pieces. Note that each piece function will have their own inverse. You will find, however, that each 1-to-1 piece will have exactly the same transformations applied to them, namely a compression of $a$ and a positive shift of $b/a$ along the x-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Write it as $$f(a(x-\frac ba))$$
Do the innermost transformation first, so this means a translation of $\frac ba$ horizontally followed by an enlargement horizontally by factor $\frac 1a$

Comment: Your answer is Method 3 and I personally think it is the right answer, but I saw in a reliable book that said first enlargement and then translation (Method 2). Is the book wrong?